# My react app in the gh-pages is only showing the read.me not the index.js;

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

My react app is not loading the index.js, you can see my repository at https://github.com/Vitorrrocha/Star-Wars-info and the gh-pages: https://vitorrrocha.github.io/Star-Wars-info/ .

package.json: https://github.com/Vitorrrocha/Star-Wars-info/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which branch are you trying to serve as a GitHub page? I see you have just a master branch.

You could make a branch called gh-pages and push your build there. I see you have gh-pages installed as a devDependency. You can use `gh-pages -d build` it will do everything for you. (build is the output folder of react-scripts build.)

Comment: I putted in  "build": "gh-pages -d build", but now i need to delete and load again the repository by a gh-pages branch ?

Comment: Let build stay what it was. Make "deploy": "gh pages -d build". And use "predeploy": "npm run build".

Comment: I did what you said but not happened. :(

Comment: Now it´s online in: https://vitorrrocha.github.io//Star-Wars-info/ but i lost my repository on github.

Comment: I don´t know what i did but now it´s working, anyway thanks you. :)